# php convert foreign language chars to "string"

Tags: php

> **UPDATE**: Please ignore this question, it appears that md5 is not
>   returning result because I pass the URL through filter_var($url,
>   FILTER_SANITIZE_URL) and looks like FILTER_SANITIZE URL doesn't work
>   for foreign characters.

I have a problem where I want to get a hash from URLs e.g

> [https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/추간판_탈출증](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%B6%94%EA%B0%84%ED%8C%90_%ED%83%88%EC%B6%9C%EC%A6%9D)

The URL is provided by user in a form with  so I assume it's already UTF-8 since my website is UTF-8.

However the above cannot be used with md5() as it returns empty result. May I know what php function do I use to convert it to something like below where md5() can be used?

> https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%B6%94%EA%B0%84%ED%8C%90_%ED%83%88%EC%B6%9C%EC%A6%9D

I tried iconv, htmlspecialchar, htmlentities and I cannot seems to be able to find the right function to convert the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use directly `md5` to Encode whole URL as Below :

```
echo md5('https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/추간판_탈출증');
```

Which gives output as :

```
26eb333445f4e154f8ecb76e7c2ac858
```

**UPDATED :**

As Per [w3schools FILTER_SANITIZE_URL](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/filter_sanitize_url.asp)

> The FILTER_SANITIZE_URL filter removes all illegal URL characters from
>   a string.
>
> This filter allows all letters, digits and
>   $-_.+!*'(),{}|\^~[]`"><#%;/?:@&=

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, it appears that $sanitize = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); was giving me problems thats why my md5 returns empty or not accurate hash.

Comment: @Someone Special, Why don't you directly use `md5()` to solve your problem, insteadof `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` ?

Comment: Because I wanted to ensure it's a valid URL before I save it.

Comment: @Someone Special, You may accept the answer OR Delete the question if you consider invalid question.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [`rawurlencode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php). However you will have to extract the part of the url you want to encode or the whole url will be encoded.

```
$encoded = rawurlencode('추간판_탈출증');
// value of $encoded is now '%EC%B6%94%EA%B0%84%ED%8C%90_%ED%83%88%EC%B6%9C%EC%A6%9D'
```

Answer (score 0):

use urlencode(url) function for conversion

once check this url [url encode functions are found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)